# Android Studio - Facebook Login button render error

Tags: facebook, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem regarding the Facebook SDK and the Login Button. When I tried to put the Login Button, I receive this message

```
Rendering Problems

The following classes could not be found:

com.facebook.widget.LoginButton (Fix Build Path, Create Class) Tip: Try to build the project
```

I don't know why Android Studio is not rendering the button. I added the module successfully, I can use Facebook SDK classes like Session and so...

Do you know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Android Studio is a v0.1 early access **preview**

Please report bugs here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list not expect a bug fix on SO

Comment: I reported the bug here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55461&q=facebook%20android%20studio&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars